# $2\operatorname{D}$ heat equation with non-zero initial condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I cant find anything about $2\operatorname{D}$ heat equation with non-zero initial condition, need to find the temperature of the rectangle.

[image]

Comment: I suppose that there are three variables $x,y,t$ where $t$ is the time. The initial conditions are missing. The graph gives the conditions at the borders (at any time or at time $0$ only ?). The conditions at time $t=0$ inside the rectangle are missing.

Comment: the lower side of R is kept at temperature f(x) while others are kept at 0C , i dont know anything else

Comment: If you don't know the temperatures inside the rectangle at time $t=0$, the problem is undetermined.